# How to use Twilio Mobile number for calls and SMS with Android Softphone App

Tags: android, twilio, sms

I have an Twilio Mobile number that has both voice and SMS functionality. I would like to set this up to make/receive calls and send/receive SMS in MuzuDroid Android Softphone app.

I can find how to set it up to make and receive calls, but I do not know how to set it up to send/receive SMS. Does anyone know how to set this up or if this is even possible?

If it is not possible, can anyone recommend a Softphone App that can do both calls and SMS with a Twilio mobile number?

Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: This site is for programming questions only.  If you were trying to write your own app that uses twilio, it could be on topic.  Asking how to setup another app isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a softphone app for the phone but maybe the [Twilio Dev Phone](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/dev-phone) also does the job for you.

[image: dev phone]

It's basically a soft phone you can start via the Twilio CLI and use from the browser.